# Python cannot find a local module even though the parent folder is in sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder  structure like this:

```
/content
  /repo
    /examples
      __init__.py
      /utils
        __init__.py
        helper.py
```

Within a Jupyter notebook cell, I run this:

```
!pwd
```

And I get this:

```
/content
```

Next:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/content/repo")
sys.path
```

And the result:

```
['',
 '/env/python',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/root/.ipython',
 '/content/repo']
```

Finally, I run this:

```
from examples.utils.helper import read_data
```

And I get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-b350ec0401b3> in <module>()
----> 1 from examples.utils.helper import read_data

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'examples.utils'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If it helps, this is a Colab notebook.

**[UPDATE]**

With @John Gordon's help, now I know that the problem is that the machine has already got an `examples` package on it. But considering the fact that I also added my path to the beginning of the `sys.path`, why the issue is still there?

This is what my `sys.path` looks right now:

```
['/content/repo/',
 '/content/repo',
 '',
 '/env/python',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/root/.ipython',
 '/content/repo/',
 '/content/repo']
```

Comment: Use ‘sys.path.insert(0, path)’

Comment: @mamun The same error

Comment: `/content/repo` is at the end of your path.  Is there some other module named `examples` that occurs earlier in the path?  Try this: `import examples; print (examples.__file__)`

Comment: It returns `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/examples/__init__.py` which is definitely not the right path. But my problem is that I even added the local path to the beginning of the `sys.path` and that did not solve the issue either!

Comment: @Mehran : Once `examples` has been found, it’s locked in for that process (absent hacking on `sys.modules`).  Start over (or rename your package!).